# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

I'm new to selenium python. right now i'm trying to run python code that already converted from selenium Ide. when i'm ran the code i got this error. i'm using eclipse to run the code

```
ERROR: test_isnin2 (__main__.Isnin2)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_isnin2 (__main__.Isnin2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\python\src\Isnin2.py", line 20, in test_isnin2
    driver.get("/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.4.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.4.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 144, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.4.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 111, in check_response
    zeroeth = value['stackTrace'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 35.406s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

my coding as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class Isnin2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://www.google.com.my/"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_isnin2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("em").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("selenium python")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Setting Up Selenium with Python").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("selenium.py").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

i'm really hope someone can help me since i'm new to selenium python.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you do not supply your `base_url` to the `driver`. Maybe you should replace this line:

```
driver.get("/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
```

with something like this:

```
driver.get(self.base_url + "/search?q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
```

**EDIT**:

Also: do you want to test something with the `is_element_present` method? With the Python unittest framework the method name has to start with `test`. So if you want it as a test rename it to `test_is_element_present`.

Additionally: If you plan multiple tests on a response, you should place the `driver.get()` call in the `setUp` method, because the order of the test does not necessarily have to be the same as you have written the tests. `setUp` on the other hand is guaranteed to be run before any tests are called.

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment on Constantinius answer if I could, but I don't have the rep . . .

I used this question as an excuse to look into the IDE - looks like the code above is pretty much a straight export to Python Webdriver, and in my test case, it results in the same malformed .get (where the base_url is not provided).

The rest of the issues Constantinius mentions are a result of the IDE's limited abilities.  The is_element_present method looks like it's part of a work in process in the IDE, and I'm guessing it's a placeholder for actual checks.